# How can I group a list of IDs based on the highest number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written some code that writes a list

```
<ul class="portfolios" style="opacity: 1;">
<li class="image0">
<li class="image1">
<li class="image2">
<li class="image3">
<li class="image4">
<li class="image5">
<li class="image6">
<li class="image0">
<li class="image1">
<li class="image2">
<li class="image3">
<li class="image4">
<li class="image5">
<li class="image6">
<li class="image7">
<li class="image8">
<li class="image9">
<li class="image10">
<li class="image0">
<li class="image1">
<li class="image2">
<li class="image3">
<li class="image4">
<li class="image5">
<li class="image6">
<li class="image7">
</ul>
```

I can't change the HTML too much as it's an array each statement that is writing the list. I want to know if it's possible to take the first lot of classes image0 - image6 and wrap them in a div the same with the second lot of image classes image0-image7 and the third lot image0-image10.

This code isn't pretty but it works, I just would like to wrap in a div.

Any ideas?

Changed from ID to class, same problem though

I want to produce this...

```
<ul class="portfolios" style="opacity: 1;">
    <li class="image0">
    <li class="image1">
    <li class="image2">
    <li class="image3">
    <li class="image4">
    <li class="image5">
    <li class="image6">
</ul>
<ul class="portfolios" style="opacity: 1;">
    <li class="image0">
    <li class="image1">
    <li class="image2">
    <li class="image3">
    <li class="image4">
    <li class="image5">
    <li class="image6">
    <li class="image7">
    <li class="image8">
    <li class="image9">
    <li class="image10">
</ul>
<ul class="portfolios" style="opacity: 1;">
    <li class="image0">
    <li class="image1">
    <li class="image2">
    <li class="image3">
    <li class="image4">
    <li class="image5">
    <li class="image6">
    <li class="image7">
</ul>
```

Comment: The id attr must be unique, wrapped in a div or not.

Comment: The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique, so having two elements with the same `id` is invalid and will likely cause problems.

Comment: For a better understanding: Do you want "wrap" each list item (<li>) into a seperate div or the whole list?

Comment: ok i will change it to classes, fair point but how can i wrap each set of classes?

Comment: If it helps anyone the reason this is outputted this way is explained here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575732/how-can-i-load-multiple-pages-into-multiple-divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/b7KkU/

**relevant jquery:**

```
//Create the other two ul's (I've added id's for convenienece)
$("body")
    .append("<ul id='two' class='portfolios'>")
    .append("<ul id='three' class='portfolios'>");

portfoliosLen = $(".portfolios li").length;

for (i=0; i<portfoliosLen; i++) {
    if (i < 7) { // <-- first 7 li
        //Do nothing (Basically, leave it in this ul)
    }
    else if (i >= 7 && i < 15 ) { // <-- next 8 li
        //Move to second ul
        $(".portfolios li").eq(7).appendTo("ul#two");
        /*
          From the above code eq(7) remains constant. eq(7) = 8th li
          This means take the 8th element from this ul and move it.              
        */
    }
    else { // <-- remaining li
        //Move to third ul
        $(".portfolios li").eq(7).appendTo("ul#three");
        /*
          On each iteration of the for loop, we're taking the 8th li
          and moving it somewhere.
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: LEGEND! this is exactly what I need !! w00t ! hmm, can i ask is it possible to create as many ul's as needed? I have some instances where 7 ul's would need to be created and other times just 2. it'll depend on the initial .portfolio list

Comment: @Tara Please note that the above code will work only if the number of photos is known for each portfolio (which I doubt is the case, else you would simply directly write HTML instead of getting into jQuery...). You should correct the problem at its root (generate directly something correct) rather than trying to patch it.

Comment: Yeah I found a better way to output it, thanks so much for the suggestions tho I used it for another project where the img number was the same for each, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You are (and will be) producing invalid HTML:

- IDs must be unique within the document
- The ul element cannot contain div elements

Try to paste the following code into http://validator.w3.org/check and see the errors

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
  <head><title>Blah</title></head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li id="myli_1">Blah</li>
      <div>
        <li id="myli_2">Blah</li>
        <li id="myli_1">Blah</li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Instead you should:

- Group your images into separate UL elements
- Assign them a unique ID if this is really needed

For instance :

```
<ul id="portfolio0" class="portfolios">
  <li id="image0_0" class="ui-draggable">
  <li id="image0_1" class="ui-draggable">
  <li id="image0_2" class="ui-draggable">
  <li id="image0_3" class="ui-draggable">
  <li id="image0_4" class="ui-draggable">
  <li id="image0_5" class="ui-draggable">
  <li id="image0_6" class="ui-draggable">
</ul>

<ul id="portfolio1" class="portfolios">
  <li id="image1_0" class="ui-draggable">
  <li id="image1_1" class="ui-draggable">
  <li id="image1_2" class="ui-draggable">
  <li id="image1_3" class="ui-draggable">
  <li id="image1_4" class="ui-draggable">
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to do this, using jQuery